# How to dissect a large legacy codebase and start using TDD

Tags: tdd

If I was to inherit a large codebase, how would I start refactor the application using TDD?

The application has layers of authentication(financial banking company), and frankly, not knowing where to start is a big issue.

I guess follow up is, is it worth the time and effort to start using TDD if the code is not "testable"?

Comment: If a question is to help with home work, you need to mention it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This book is exactly what you need: *[Working Effectively with Legacy Code](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0131177052)* by Michael Feathers.

That book goes directly to both of your questions: How to start refactoring a legacy codebase, and how to approach TDD when the code is not yet testable.

Underlying both of those questions is another that the book answers: How to get a legacy codebase under test.